# how to set custom http header in jBoss

Tags: internet-explorer, jboss, http-headers

I want to set the emulateIE7 tag on per site basis. For that I'll need to set the same tag in http header. I am using jboss. So can anyone please tell me how to add custom http header in jboss..

Comment: That's too vague. Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.addHeader(String, String)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to add headers to a response.

You can access the HttpServletResponse in a [`Servlet`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), JSP or a (Servlet) [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).